# Number signs in \mintinline in \footnote

Tags: minted, catcodes, syntax-highlighting

I'm having an issue with typesetting code using the minted package when I want to highlight for example `print(x) # prints x` in a footnote:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
Comments in Python\footnote{\mintinline{python}{print(x) # prints x}}.
\end{document}
```

The issue is that `#` is printed twice:

[image]

If I were to highlight code with the percent sign, I could change its catcode:

```
\catcode`\%=11
Comments in \TeX\footnote{\mintinline{tex}{\LaTeX % comment}}.
```

However, changing the catcode of `#` gives an error, since it is used in the definition of `\mintinline`. The error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\PYG #1#2->\FV@PYG 
                   {#1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart #2\FancyVerbBreakStop }
l.2 ...x}\PYG{p}{)} \PYG{c+c1}{\PYGZsh{} prints x}
```

How can I fix this (in a scalable way)? I intend to use this quite a lot, since `#` is a common character in the ARM assembly code I intend to typeset. (I cannot provide an ARM example here, since the ARM lexer is not in the latest pygments release yet).

Comment: The minted documentation that things get complicated when putting `\mintinline` in for example footnotes when using `#` and `%`, but does not give a solution.

Comment: There might not be a direct solution. If there's another macro grabbing the `\mintinline` everything is tokenized. Isn't there a macro to *define* something, like `\defmintinline\name{print(x) # prints x}`? Then you can use `\name` whenever you want and it works right.

Comment: @Manuel you were right, thanks. It turned out to be in the FAQ section, where I didn't look at first. I wrote an answer about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dealing with verbatim material in footnotes is always a pain.

You can do this in two steps: defining the string to typeset and then use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{minted}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mintedstring}{mv}
 {
  \tl_clear_new:c { l_minted_string_#1_tl }
  \tl_set:cn { l_minted_string_#1_tl } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mintinlinestring}{mm}
 {
  \minted_inline_string:nv { #1 } { l_minted_string_#2_tl }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \minted_inline_string:nn
 {
  \mintinline{#1}{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \minted_inline_string:nn { nv }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\textheight}{2cm} % just to keep the picture small

\begin{document}

Comments in Python%
  \mintedstring{print}{print(x) # prints x}%
  \footnote{\mintinlinestring{python}{print}}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This should be in the package, in my opinion, it's a really useful thing and leaves out all the “pain” of footnotes, for instance; and also the possibility to define multiline verbatim code and use it later. Similar to the behaviour in ConTeXt.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't notice the font size yet. Minted is on github, are you interested in making a pull request? If you don't have the time for that, I can also do it.

Answer (score 2):

I dove further into the documentation and it turns out there is something written about it:

> **I want to use `\mintinline` in a context that normally doesn’t allow
>   verbatim content.** The `\mintinline` command will already work in many
>   places that do not allow normal verbatim commands like `\verb`, so make
>   sure to try it first. If it doesn’t work, one of the simplest alternatives is to save your code in a box, and then use it later. For example,
>
> ```
> \newsavebox\mybox
> \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
> \mintinline{cpp}{std::cout}
> \end{lrbox}
>
> \commandthatdoesnotlikeverbatim{Text \usebox{\mybox}}
> ```

Hence, my code could be adapted to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
  \mintinline{python}{print(x) # prints x}
\end{lrbox}
Comments in Python\footnote{\usebox{\mybox}}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't get the right font size.